# access non-static field of another class (system) as if it is my own field - elegantly

Tags: c++, design-patterns, field, c++14

How to enable a system (`SystemB1`) to access a field of another system (`SystemA::sub`) as if it is its own field?

- `SystemA` is a utility system with its own field `Sub* sub`.
- `SystemB1` - `SystemB5` are systems that want to access `SystemA::sub` easily.
- There are other systems, but it is not related to `SystemA` or any `SystemB`. (not shown)

Here is a working [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/201caf7c627ae5ad).

```
class SystemA;
class SystemB1;
class Core{
    public:
    SystemA* systemA=nullptr;
    SystemB1* systemB1=nullptr;
    //SystemB2,B3,B4,B5
};
//"SystemA.h"
class Sub1{
    public: void f(){std::cout<<"OK"<<std::endl;}
    //has 10-20 function
};
class SystemA : public Core{
    public: Sub1* sub1=new Sub1();
    //has 5-10 subsystems (Sub1 Sub2 Sub3 ...)
};
//"SystemB1.h"
class SystemB1 : public Core{
    public: void fB1();
};
//"SystemB1.cpp" , include "SystemA.h"
void SystemB1::fB1(){
    systemA->sub1->f(); //<--- Can it be more concise like `sub->f()` ?
}
```

**Note :-** (just in case it is related)

- In real case, it uses service locator pattern (1 system ~ 1 service) and `Sub1* sub1` is not a pointer but has `operator->()`.
- In real case, `Sub1` is an ugly template type e.g. `Sub<std::unordered_map<EnemyShip,Turret>>`.   Thus the most convenient way to refer to type of `sub1` (if needed) is to use `decltype`.

### Question

Are there any design pattern / C++ magic (except macro) to abbreviate `systemA->sub1->f();` to something shorter like `sub1->f();`?

Sorry if it seems to be a very trivial question.
I want to improve my skill and productivity - every little thing can help.

### My poor solution

The only solution I found is to create a **base** class for `SystemB1,B2,...` named `SystemB`.

```
//need #include SystemA
class SystemB : public Core{
    //Solution 1 : cached from SystemA's
    public: decltype(SystemA::sub1.operator->()) sub1; 
    //  decltype(SystemA::sub2.operator->()) sub2; 

    //Solution 2 :
    public:  decltype(SystemA::sub1.operator->()) getSub1();  
    // decltype(SystemA::sub2.operator->()) getSub2();  
};
```

Then, `SystemB1,B2...` will be able to call `sub1->f1()` or `getSub1()->f1()` directly.

**Disadvantage:**

- Whenever I add a new `subX` to `SystemA` :-

  - (Solution 1) I have to create a new field `SystemB::subX` and set it with a correct pointer.
  - (Solution 2) I have to add `SystemB::getSubX()` with correct implementation.
- It is very ugly.    `decltype` is needed, because if I declare `Sub1* sub1` inside `SystemB` :-

  - Whenever I change type of `SystemA::sub1` e.g. from `Sub<std::unordered_map<EnemyShip,Turret>>` to `Sub<std::unordered_map<EnemyShip,Tracker>>` in `SystemA` I have to also change type of field or return type of function in `SystemB` which cause some maintainability problem.

Comment: Leaving aside all the template and typing issues, what you need is a reference.

Comment: @EJP I guess so.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SystemA : public Core
{
public:
    Sub1 *sub1 = new Sub1();
    //has 5-10 subsystems (Sub1 Sub2 Sub3 ...)
    static SystemA &GetInstance();
};

SystemA &SystemA::GetInstance()
{
    static SystemA sa;
    return sa;
}

//"SystemB1.h"
class SystemB1 : public Core
{
private:
    SystemA *systemA;
public:
    void SystemB1()
    {
        // use this
        systemA = new SystemA(...);
        // or this
        systemA = &SystemA::GetInstance();
    }
    void fB1();
};

//"SystemB1.cpp" , include "SystemA.h"
void SystemB1::fB1()
{
    systemA->sub1->f(); //<--- Can it be more concise like `sub->f()` ?
}
```

First object SystemA always create with call `GetInstance`.

For example:

```
SystemA *m_mainSystem = &SystemA::GetInstance();
```

Also, look at code of system which was writting on c++ [FFmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffmpeg.c).

Comment: Do I miss something?   I don't think that `m_systemApointer->sub1->f();` is any better than  `systemA->sub1->f();`.

Comment: @cppBeginner if you will use method getInstance you can get access for SystemA from any class

Comment: It is already possible even without this solution.  `systemA` is already a field of `Core`.   ......  Hmm, after editing, I see no improvement - `systemA->sub1->f();` is still the same.  May you clarify it a little more please?

Comment: @cppBeginner I just propose you technology which help you get access for every member of any class from every member of other class.

Comment: @cppBeginner you can create method `GetInstance` in `Core` and get access to object `systemA` by call `Core::GetInstance()->systemA`

Comment: While it might be useful, it doesn't answer the question that ask about "how to abbreviate".  ....  You just suggest a way to "elongate" it.  (sad face)

Comment: @cppBeginner You should not try to shorten code, you should try to write code by c++ standart.

Comment: Are there any high-quality code that has many lines long like `systemA->sub1->f();`?  May you provide some examples?

Comment: @cppBeginner For example [FFmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffmpeg.c) or [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp)

Comment: Thank.  The first link is stunning for me.  (The second one - a long variable name - is not so related.)    IMHO, both comments are more useful than the code in the solution.  I will upvote if you put it there XD.

Comment: @cppBeginner i paste link on FFmpeg in my answer. if my answer helped to solve your problem - mark it. good luck :)